# Getting a Rails model's association's association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model called `salon` that `has_many` `stylists` that `has_many` `appointments`.

I can of course do `@salon.stylists` and I can do `@stylist.appointments`, but I can't do `@salon.appointments`.

Is such a thing possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add:

```
has_many :appointments, :through => :stylists
```

to your `salon` class